# Using re.finditer to generate iterative object, but no return, the regex code is ok when testing separately

Tags: regex, logging, python-re

**Here is the regex code**

```
pattern="""
(?P<host>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
(\ \-\ )
(?P<user_name>[a-z]{1,100}\d{4}|\-{1})
( \[)(?P<time>\d{2}\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/\d{4}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\ -\d{4})
(\] ")
(?P<request>.+)
(")
"""
for item in re.finditer(pattern,text,re.VERBOSE):
    # We can get the dictionary returned for the item with .groupdict()
    print(item.groupdict())
```

**And I use Jupyter Notebook to run those codes.**

**The testing text is**

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
```

Comment: [Your pattern seems to not be matching](https://regex101.com/r/nwdY0V/1).

Comment: It pattern works if you don't use re.VERBOSE with the right formatting https://ideone.com/vdFmWx

Comment: As an aside, slash and minus do not need to be backslash-escaped (though inside a character class the latter might make sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you did not escape the literal space in your pattern. When using `re.X` / `re.VERBOSE` any whitespace (when outside of a character class) in the pattern is treated as formatted whitespace and not accounted for in the end. In Python `re` pattern, `[ ]` will *always* match a literal space, but this is not guaranteed in other language flavors, so the best way to match a space in the pattern that is compiled with the `re.X` like flag is *escaping the space*.

Besides, there are other things to note:

- `{1}` is always redundant, remove it
- Repeated patterns can be grouped in a non-capturing group and quantified with an appropriate quantifier, e.g. `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` => `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`
- There is no need to escape `/` and `:` (anywhere in the pattern) and `-` (when outside a character class) in the `re` regex.

Thus, you can use

```py
pattern = r'''(?P<host>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
(\ -\ )
(?P<user_name>[a-z]{1,100}\d{4}|-)
(\ \[)(?P<time>\d{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\ -\d{4})
(\]\ ")
(?P<request>.+)
(")'''
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZFm5z/1/) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3FZWmb):

```py
import re
text = '''146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554'''
pattern = r'''(?P<host>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
(\ -\ )
(?P<user_name>[a-z]{1,100}\d{4}|-)
(\ \[)(?P<time>\d{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\ -\d{4})
(\]\ ")
(?P<request>.+)
(")'''
for item in re.finditer(pattern,text,re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict()) # We can get the dictionary returned for the item with .groupdict()
```

Output:

```py
{'host': '146.204.224.152', 'user_name': 'feest6811', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}
{'host': '197.109.77.178', 'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and it perfectly worked. I used https://regex101.com/ to test my regex repression and it requires to escape "/" but in my jupyter notebook, escaping or not escaping are both fine. As you mentioned, the main problem is the whitespace.

Comment: @user9155539 regex101 does not require escaping `/` if you select Python regex flavor.